# ORA-00918: Column ambiguously defined (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to select a column as `' '` (empty).

Here is my query:

```
SELECT NAME, ' ', ' ' 
FROM TABLE_NAME 
GROUP BY NAME
```

While executing at the database level query there is no problem, but at the code level I am getting `Column ambiguously defined` Error.

**Note** From suggestions, that error is because of `' '`. So,  I wanted to follow

```
SELECT NAME, ' ' AS EMPTY1, ' ' AS EMPTY2 
FROM TABLE_NAME 
GROUP BY NAME
```

How long it's correct or any alternatives, please?

Comment: Both queries work for me. What exactly is your problem?

Comment: @ErsinGülbahar: neither of those queries will result in an ORA-00918 error - not even when used from within a programming language

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name you are right

Answer (score 1):

### Your solution is correct.

### alternative:

```
SELECT  distinct NAME, 
' ' AS EMPTY1, 
' ' AS EMPTY2 
FROM TABLE_NAME
```